# Global HIV Incidence Raw Data

Tags: data-request, medical, global

All information I can find on global HIV incidence broken down into male/female categories is in the form of already processed charts. I've attempted to find a raw HIV dataset that breaks down into a number of categories (drug user, gender, country etc) however these datasets seem to require that I am affiliated with an academic institution and that I am conducting a study, which must be authorized (eg: [[1]](http://dhsprogram.com/data/Dataset-Types.cfm)) (I don't fall into any of these categories, as this project is an independent curiosity of mine).

Would anyone know how I could go about getting access to raw, categorized, global HIV incidence data where I'm not required to be affiliated with an academic institution?

Comment: Have you looked at [AIDSinfo Online Database](http://www.aidsinfoonline.org/devinfo/libraries/aspx/Home.aspx)?

Comment: @long - Thank you, that's what I'm looking for, although the data is a bit confusing as it's categorized into strategy programs rather than merely incidence of infections.

Comment: Did you try the WHO Global Health Observatory? That's where I got a lot of cholera data (as .csv's, if I recall correctly).

Comment: Have you found an answer for this? I guess a single country or region would be more likely than global data with demographics.

Comment: Is the drug user an example or a required stratification?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a tremendous variety of data on HIV available from World Health Organization: http://www.who.int/hiv/data/en/

This site also seems to have fantastic data plus it lists sources: https://ourworldindata.org/hiv-aids#data-sources

CDC: https://www.cdc.gov/hiv/statistics/overview/

UN data: http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=hiv&d=UNAIDS&f=inID%3a35

I hope some of these help.